Angular app working in Firefox but not in Chrome
I am working on an Angular app with following versions:
"@angular/animations": "^17.0.0",
"@angular/cdk": "^17.3.7",
"@angular/common": "^17.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^17.0.0",
"@angular/core": "^17.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "^17.0.0",
"@angular/material": "^17.3.8",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^17.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.0.0",
"@angular/router": "^17.0.0",

in the homepage I have a mat-sidenav-container that contains a list of options and a mat-icon-button that toggles the sidenav when clicked; when clicking on one option of the sidenav menu, another component with a mat-table is loaded into the page. This works fine in Firefox but in Chrome only the top bar is shown and when the menu is clicked the sidebar does not work.
In the console I am not getting any error.
How is this possible? are there some issue about compatibility with my angular material version and the chrome version (125.0.6422.141)?
Thanks for your help!

Do you have the Angular dev tools installed in Chrome? If so, does your component tree look correct? When inspecting the page, how does the elements panel differ in Chrome vs Firefox? Are things missing from the DOM?

Thanks for your reply, the Angular dev tool extension is very useful. The elements are all there, the problem is that their content is not visible apparently. By hovering the different DOM elements I saw them being highlighted on the page without any content.
